# Load an array with no name (JSON) (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to pull JSON through an HTTP get method in swift that looks exactly like the following:

> [{"name":"John", age: "Fifteen"},{"name":"Sue","age":"sixteen"}]

My goal is to create a function that can pull that data and put it into individual cells. My only issue is how to format the structure as there is no name to the array.

This is what my structure looks like:

```
struct SearchResponse: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let age: String?
}
```

And this is how I'm (trying) to gather the data:

```
  guard let data = data else { return }
                                  do {
                                      
  let obj: SearchResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(SearchResponse.self, from: data)
                                    
  let searchObj = SearchObject(age: obj.age ?? "", name: obj.name ?? "")

                                          
                                
                                  
self.search_object = searchObj ?? []
```

Number of rows is section is:

```
return search_object.count
```

When I run the code the cells are just returning as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of `SearchResponse`s, so you have to decode it as an array of `SearchResponse`s:

```
guard let data = data else { return }

do {
    let objects = try JSONDecoder().decode([SearchResponse].self, from: data)
    let searchObjects = objects.map {
        SearchObject(age: $0.age ?? "", name: $0.name ?? "")
    }

    self.search_object = searchObjects

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or just make `SearchObject` itself conform to `Codable` and remove the need for `SearchResponse` entirely:

```
struct SearchObject: Codable {
    let age: String?
    let name: String?
}

[...]

guard let data = data else { return }

do {
    self.search_object = try JSONDecoder().decode([SearchObject].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```